# Inherit sublayouts created inside sitecore CMS in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, sitecore

Is there any way I can use the layouts and sublayouts I have created inside the Sitecore CMS, in Visual Studio to write the c# codes assuming that I have Sitecore Rocks plug in installed on my VS? Also while setting a new connection I am not able to get physical access of my Sitecore instance.

I checked for the same over the internet but could not find any reference. Help required.
Thanking everyone in advance

Comment: I don't think this is possible, as you need to compile your code behind code.

Comment: Created through developer center I assume?

Answer (score 0):

solved the issue!!  Brad Christie assumed it right!! I created it using developer center without any dependency from VS. you can create a sublayout from developer center which gives you an option to include .cs page too if you would like to and you can write your codes directly in your .cs page.